# Weird Python dictionary behavior

Tags: python, dictionary

In Python 3.6:

```
d = {0: None}
for i in d:
    del d[i]
    d[i+1] = None
    print(i)
```

The output is

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

In Python 2.7 the output goes up to `7`.  What causes this output?

Comment: I get the "expected" output on Python 3.4 as well.

Comment: Wow, that was fast.  Someone nerd-sniped me at work with this last night.  Thanks for finding the duplicate question (I swear I looked all morning!).

Comment: FYI, I googled "python modify dict while iterating".

Comment: @JohnKugelman Cool, thanks.  Since you have so much rep can you hard-delete this question for me?

Comment: Only if it gets downvoted. No need to delete it, though. It's not bad to have duplicates with different wording.